# how to send mail to selected contact as well as bulk selection from the list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

am having some problem to identified about "how to and where to start". i just have got contact list from existing resource. and i add some functionality that would able to send mail using Nodemailer.

what i wish to achieve ?

1. send mail to selected contacts
2. send mail to more than one contact
    Ex: am having 10 contacts in the list, i want to send same mail to selected
          4 contacts from the list

i really don't understand how to integrate this part. 
Here am using **MongoDB, Nodejs, AngularJs**

**could anyone pls tell me how push selected contact to into loop for sending mail**

kindly check the below codes:

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <title>Contact List App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">       
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>select all</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.name">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.email">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.number">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addContact()">Add Contact</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="update()">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="contact.Selected" />
                    </td>
                    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(contact._id)">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit(contact._id)">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning">mail</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var from, to, subject, text;
        $("#send_email").click(function() {
            to = $("#to").val();
            subject = $("#subject").val();
            text = $("#content").val();
            //$("#message").text("Sending E-mail...Please wait");
            alert("mail has been sent to " + to + "successfully pls check the inbox");
            $.get("http://localhost:3000/send", {
                to: to,
                subject: subject,
                text: text
            }, function(data) {
                if (data == "sent") {
                    $("#message").empty().html("<p>Email is been sent at " + to + " . Please check inbox !</p>");
                }

            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    #container {
        margin-left: 400px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #to,
    #subject,
    #content {
        font-family: "Segoe UI";
        font-size: 18px;
        width: 530px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family: "Segoe UI";
        font-size: 40px;
        color: #3b5998;
    }

    p {
        color: green;
    }

    #send_email {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: "Segoe UI";
    }

    #message {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <div id="container">
        <form>
            <label>email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="to">
            <br>
            <label>subject</label>
            <input type="text" id="subject" p>
            <br>
            <label>body of the msg</label>
            <textarea id="content" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
            <br>
            <button onClick="window.location.reload()" id="send_email">send</button>
            <br>
            <span id="message"></span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

### Server.js

```
// MEAN Stack RESTful API Tutorial - Contact List App

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('contactlist', ['contactlist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/contactlist', function(req, res) {
    console.log('I received a GET request');

    db.contactlist.find(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

app.post('/contactlist', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.contactlist.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.delete('/contactlist/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.contactlist.remove({ _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id) }, function(err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.get('/contactlist/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.contactlist.findOne({ _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id) }, function(err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.put('/contactlist/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(req.body.name);
    db.contactlist.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id) },
        update: { $set: { name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, number: req.body.number } },
        new: true
    }, function(err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});


app.post('/contactlist', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("this is test request check");
});

app.listen(3010);
console.log("Server running on port 3010");



var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'example@gmail.com',
        pass: 'password'
    },
    tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    debug: true
});


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
app.get('/send', function(req, res) {
    var mailOptions = {
        to: req.query.to,
        subject: req.query.subject,
        text: req.query.text
    }
    console.log(mailOptions);
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.end("error");
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            res.end("sent");
        }
    });
});
```

### controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");


    var refresh = function() {
        $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response) {
            console.log("I got the data I requested");
            $scope.contactlist = response;
            $scope.contact = "";
        });
    };

    $scope.checkAll = function() {
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.contactlist, function(item) {
            item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
        });

    };


    refresh();

    $scope.addContact = function() {
        console.log($scope.contact);
        $http.post('/contactlist', $scope.contact).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            refresh();
        });
    };

    $scope.remove = function(id) {
        console.log(id);
        $http.delete('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
            refresh();
        });
    };

    $scope.edit = function(id) {
        console.log(id);
        $http.get('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
            $scope.contact = response;
        });
    };

    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.contact._id);
        $http.put('/contactlist/' + $scope.contact._id, $scope.contact).success(function(response) {
            refresh();
        })
    };

    $scope.deselect = function() {
        $scope.contact = "";
    }


}]);
```

helps much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ideally,

You create a function which will /send api from the server. I realize you do not implement it yet.

In this function you will loop through contactlist and get contacts which selected  = true. Send list id to the server with format '1,2,3'. List id separated by comma.

Now in the server, with req.params.ids.split(',') you can get list id.

Comment: yes, i have not implemented. now going to fallow what you said. pls share what need to do further.!

Answer (score 0):

**Frontend**

You should include a functionality in Angular's controller that sends the an array of objects to an Angular Service. Each object having the email, email body (and other customization stuff if Any..). **The Angular Service should be the one which sends an http request to your server's endpoint and returns an $http promise to the controller** Always try and keep your controllers as minimal as possible. Do all the business logic in services.

**Backend**

The server should include a function that returns a promise. The promise would include nodemailer sending the stuff to just one person (I don't know if nodemailer uses any bulk emails sending functionality.. if it does, use that). 
The server can receive the request on a POST endpoint rather than a GET, recieving the array of the email objects. Then, you can loop through the array and call that promise function, each time having a then/catch/then(extra one which gets executed everytime). In the then blocks, you should store the responses for further use and finally send the appropriate response back to the client.

That's basically it and that's how I did it. Instead of Nodemailer, I used mailgun's node module because that's what I was using to send mails.

Comment: thank you @Amin Mohamed Ajani . am working on it .. and come back if i face any issues. mostly i ll sorted it out for my own if cant ll come back as you ppls